# LiteDb crashing when retrieving a Collection with a Dictionary

Tags: .net, dictionary, crash, litedb

Firstly, I'm using LiteDb Runtime Vv2.0.50727. This is because I am having to develop in Framework 3.5.

Consider the pocos:

```
Public Class Controller

    Public Property ID As ObjectId = ObjectId.NewObjectId
    
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property Controls As New List(Of stig.Control)

    Public Property ControlGroups As new Dictionary(Of stig.Control, List(Of stig.Control)) 

End Class

Namespace stig
    Public Class Control

        Public Property ID As ObjectId = ObjectId.NewObjectId
        Public Property Name As String = "{New Control}"

    End Class
End Namespace
```

I've examined the database and you can write the data just fine:

[image]

However, it crashes when I try to retrieve the collection with:

```
Controllers = Connection.GetCollection(Of Controller)("Controllers")
```

This structure of statement works fine for all other collections and also if I omit the write of the dictionary to the database, litedb does not crash.

I'm afraid I can't explore the error either as I'm developing a plugin for another application which makes debugging a pain. It's definitely the retrieval of the dictionary though.

Would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: [The document said](https://www.litedb.org/docs/object-mapping/) that, for IDictionary<K, T>, K key must be String or a simple type (convertible using Convert.ToString(..)). Might this the cause?

Comment: Yeah - found that after wrote this, thanks. Yep - that was the issue.